# Uploading videos to Twitter using OAuth

Tags: video, upload, twitter, oauth

I am developing an iPhone app that uses Twitvid library for uploading videos to TwitVid.
This library first authenticates the app using the user-name and password input parameters. Then it uploads the video.
But, recently I switched to OAuth mechanism of authentication which leads to a web-page where user can enter the user-name and password.
So, I cannot provide the input fields for user-name and password in my app for uploading video.

Can someone help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks and Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 2):

I think you have used `SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate` for Oauth. If then replace below method with existing method in `SA_OAuthTwitterController.m` file. I think this will helpful.

```
 - (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType {
    NSData              *data = [request HTTPBody];

    char                *raw = data ? (char *) [data bytes] : "";

    if (raw && strstr(raw, "cancel=")) {
        [self denied];
        return NO;
    }
    else if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"]) {
        NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"password"];
        NSLog(@"%d",range.location);
        if (range.location != NSNotFound ) {
            NSString *strPass = [str substringFromIndex:range.location+8];
            NSRange toRang = [strPass rangeOfString:@"&oauth_token="];
            strPass = [strPass substringToIndex:toRang.location];
            NSArray *tempArray = [strPass componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            if ([tempArray count]) {
                strPass = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setObject:strPass forKey:@"pass"];
            }
        }
    }
    if (navigationType != UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) 
        _webView.alpha = 0.1;
    return YES;
}
```

Cheers,
Pragnesh